# Is there a update like method for angular $q?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I see that we can handle promise notifications in angular but it appears only as a third callback passed to the then function. Is there a `myPromise.update()` method?

```
'use strict';

export default function (mod) {

//@ngInject
function MainController($q, $interval) {

    let time = 0;

    let def = $q.defer();


    var prom = def.promise;


    prom.then(function successHandler() {
        console.log('done');
    }, function errorHandler() {
        console.log('error');
    }, function updateHandler(v) {
        console.log(v, 'updated value'); ///is there a nicer interface for handling notify i.e. an update method?
    });


    prom.catch(function () {
        console.log('error');
    });


    var myInterval = $interval(function () {

        time += 1000;

        if (time >= 10000) {
            def.resolve();

            $interval.cancel(myInterval);

        } else {
            def.notify(time);
        }


    }, 1000);
}

mod.controller('MainController', MainController);
}
```

Comment: No, but you can use `.finally(null, function notifyCallback() { ... })` or `.then(null, null, function notifyCallback() { ... })`. Also, you appear to be doubling up on rejection handlers

Comment: That utterly sucks and is lame :( Thanks for the response.